# How can I get div container to resize vertically the same as image?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying this since last night but the code seems to get worse the more I try. I originally wanted to try and build a responsive image slider, but for some reason decided to use a UL to do so. It probably isn't needed but my problem is the same. As I resize the browser window to make it narrower, the image resizes vertically, but the div container does not. I have tried percentages, pixels, vh values, max-heights etc but nothing works to make the container resize in propotion to the image inside. The container is named .slide I have also made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7y5m2mmv/1/)

```
.slider
{
    width : 100% ;
    height : 100% ;
    position : relative ;
    padding : 0 ;
    margin : 0 ;
    background : green

}

.slide
{
    background-color : #FAFAFA ;
    width : 30% ;
    margin : auto ;
    height : 50% ;
    min-height : 330px ;
    position : relative ;
    top : 30% ;
    right : 0 ;
    left : 0 ;
    bottom : 0
}

.slide ul
{
    list-style : none ;
}

.slide ul li
{
    position : absolute ;
    left : 18% ;
    right : 18% ;
    top : 16%   
}

ul li img.photos
{
    width : 100% 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because that in the following code you have set `min-height: 330px` which does not allow the container to resize vertically. Also decrease the `height: 50%;` as I see you do not need 50% height.

*I also suggest to use `min-height` and `min-width` for image.*

```
.slide
{
    background-color : #FAFAFA ;
    width : 30% ;
    margin : auto ;
    height : 50% ;
    min-height : 330px ;
    position : relative ;
    top : 30% ;
    right : 0 ;
    left : 0 ;
    bottom : 0
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7y5m2mmv/2/)

The second possibility is that you get rid of extra div and use border and padding for the image to have white background in the behind.

Comment: Thanks Maihan, but from my own research this does not seem to be possible. The image seems to need to resize and keep its own proportions so it does not become distorted while the container is always going to resize as a percentage more as the user decides vertically or horizontally. I can't see how both image and container in equal dimensions are possible. I think the idea of a border around the image makes more sense.